# Where do I put my mocks?

Tags: c#, mocking

I'm struggling to get mocks working, for a change, and was wondering where people generally put their mock classes.  I seem to have three basic choices none of which seem to work.

I can put them in with the application assembly itself, in which case they ship with the application, which seems bad, but they are available for unit tests during the final builds and there are no circular references.  *This seems the simplest approach.*

I can create a separate mock assembly, so they are available during the unit tests, can be consumed from the application and the test application but I end up with either having to move all of the actual types to this assembly or creating circular references.

I can put them in the test assembly, but then they are unable to be used from the application itself and therefore I cant use them as a process for building up chunks of the application.

I tend to try and use the mocks for helping develop the system as well as for the testing parts and therefore I find it hard to know where to put them.  Additionally all of the final releases of code have to run through unit test processes therefore I need the mocks available during the build cycle.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to where mock classes should be placed?

thanks for any help
T

Comment: Look into the `InternalsVisibleTo` assembly attribute; it'll improve your options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

Comment: "I tend to try and use the mocks for helping develop the system" -- this seems odd. Surely a given class is either a part of the application, or a part of the tests; but not both.

Comment: @Flynn I'm already using that thanks.
@Tim - Maybe this is where I'm going wrong.  It just seems a huge shame to always have to talk all the way back through many layers to develop my system when I have these great mocks just waiting to be used.  Do you find all of your layers of your system are already coded before you work on the front end?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your mocks should go in your unit tests projects. Your application should not be dependent on your mock objects. Generally your application will use interfaces and your mocks will implement those interfaces. Your application won't need to or should reference your test project.

Comment: So you would never use your mocks to speed up and work with your application?  I started out having them in the unit test project but it seemed a huge waste if my application always had to talk all the way back to my back end while I had all of these perfectly functioning mocks there crying out to be used.

Comment: "So you would never use your mocks to speed up and work with your application?" No; keep test code out of the application. Apart from the mocks, you've got unit testing code too: is that crying out to be used?

Comment: Sorry for the dupe between the two comments, but... The key difference between the unit testing code and the mocks is that my front end needs to used some form of the back end services and classes mostly before the other layers of developers have finished coding.  I already have a lovely set of mocks for this in my test project it just seems a big shame not to be able to use them.  Do you find all of the layers below you are already coded before you work on a front end?

Comment: @Tollo mocking frameworks like RhinoMocks can help with the effort.

Comment: Tim/Adriannp thanks for the responses so far.  Would RhinoMocks solve my issue of where to put the code?  I have not looked at it but my understanding was it made the mocking process simpler rather than solved the issue of using mocks for both development and testing.

Comment: I think you are confused about what a mocked object is. If you use an object in your application then that is not a mock object. Mock objects are there to simulate the behavior of REAL objects. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object

Comment: sorry I just saw the click to show more comments hence the delay.  I'm quite confused yes :(  I have two simple requirements - first run unit tests against dummy data and second develop my front end against dummy data.  I have classes (Which I call mocks) that contain excellent dummy data that behaves in a certain way.  I guess that I should not join the two requirements together but keep them totally separate.  I'm not going to do that as its a load of work but I can understand that is the answer to my question :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Mocks should be kept in **a separate project**. We have a total of 3 options

1. Mocks in a unit test project

   Will not work if the UI project needs to use this for startup(eg:mock service/partial integration test/smoke test). Even if the test project is referenced in config file through dependency injection, we do not want to carry unit test dlls to other environments. More over focus is more on integration tests these days as [Unit tests are less productive](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/before-you-feed-unit-test-beast-s-a-n-j-ay-mohan/?trackingId=5eIFIJGSBpnGuXMEz2PnwQ%3D%3D), which of course is outside of this topic but we should realise mocks are not just about unit tests.
2. Mocks in the application projects itself(service-mocks in
   service-project)

   Developers can accidentally forget to remove the mocks. eg: a new developer tries mocks and forgets to include it in dependency config files. Let us not leave it for chances as it can hinder expansion of teams.
3. **Mocks in a separate project**.

   Here both unit test projects, as well as other startup projects, can refer this. Integration tests using front end has the additional possibility to mock a certain area(eg: external APIs). Or smoke test the UI with mocks(while other teams deploy the back end). In short, we have a lot of options to use the mock. Not tied to unit test alone.
   But the **most important benefit** is, when we want to be sure of going live, we can remove mock project(or dll) from deployment. This way if any project or config files accidentally refer the mock, **we get runtime error**. Which helps to nip it in the bud.

Answer (score 1):

What we do on our projects is identify **internal** and **external** dependencies. Mocks for internal dependencies go in the unit-test project (or a separate Mocks project if they are used across the solution). Mocks for external dependencies go into the application itself, and are then used for deployment and integration testing.

An external dependency is something that is environmental - so, Active Directory, a web-service, a database, a logger, that sort of thing. Dependency injection is handled in the same way - external dependencies get defined in a configuration file, so we can easily choose which we want to use at run-time.

An internal dependency is pretty much everything else.